# Gstreamer. Can`t make jpeg stream from webcam

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, pipeline

I try to make jpeg stream, using webcam.
So, my pipelines:

Source:

`gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw, width=640, height=480 ! jpegenc ! jpegparse !  rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5602`

Receive:

`gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5602 buffer-size=90000 ! application/x-rtp ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegparse ! queue ! jpegdec !  videoconvert ! xvimagesink`

Source pipeline starts normally, but when I start Receive pipeline, i get error.
Error:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0: Filter caps do not completely specify the output format
Additional debug info:
gstcapsfilter.c(453): gst_capsfilter_prepare_buf (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0:
Output caps are unfixed: application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)JPEG; application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, payload=(int)26, clock-rate=(int)90000
Execution ended after 0:00:00.001054576
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I'm sure I created the Receive pipeline incorrectly, but I can't figure out how to build it correctly. I will be very grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So, i found mistake, I must write some params for application/x-rtp

Source:

`gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw ! jpegenc ! jpegparse ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=10.116.0.110 port=5602`

Receive:

`gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5602 buffer-size=90000 ! application/x-rtp, encoding-name=JPEG,payload=26,clock-rate=90000 ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegparse ! queue ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink`